# React select - disappearing options

Tags: reactjs, react-select

When I load the results of a Promise via options (options being an array in state - tweaked Select. Not a Select.Async) I load a promise with `n` elements but the dropdown will only show `n-1`.
When I then onFocus, `n` numbers (correct number) is displayed.

```

```
getAddressOptions(input) {
    this.addressLookup(input)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        let response = json["Items"]
        console.log(response) 
        this.setState({
          dropdownAddressOptions: response ? response : [], 
          addressLoading: false
        })
      })
  }
```

```
the console log has `n` elements and dropdownAddressOptions has `n-1` 
See the problem in this gif:

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/l1KcPw2ME8E9I3NMk

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your code ? It would be important to see how you filter the search.

Comment: Possibly you are setting something with a duplicate key?

Comment: @fungusanthrax Don't think I am. How do keys work in react select. The objects are entirely different. both label and value

Comment: @Antoine try adding this to each <option> tag: <option key={object.value}>{potion.label}</option>

Comment: @fungusanthrax that's not how react select works is it? it's with `valueKey` / `labelKey`

Comment: I left out value. Did you try adding the key={object.value}?